# dplyr window functions with order_by and with_order

Tags: r, dplyr

BACKGROUD

dplyr has window functions. When you want to control the order of window functions,
you can use `order_by`.

DATA

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = c("ana", "bob", "caroline",
                          "bob", "ana", "caroline"),
                   order = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 18:00:00", "2015-01-01 18:05:00",
                                        "2015-01-01 19:20:00", "2015-01-01 09:07:00",
                                        "2015-01-01 08:30:00", "2015-01-01 11:11:00"),
                                        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),  
                   value = runif(6, 10, 20),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#        id               order    value
#1      ana 2015-01-01 18:00:00 19.00659
#2      bob 2015-01-01 18:05:00 13.64010
#3 caroline 2015-01-01 19:20:00 12.08506
#4      bob 2015-01-01 09:07:00 14.40996
#5      ana 2015-01-01 08:30:00 17.45165
#6 caroline 2015-01-01 11:11:00 14.50865
```

Suppose you want to use `lag()`, you can do the following.

```
arrange(mydf, id, order) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(check = lag(value))

#        id               order    value    check
#1      ana 2015-01-01 08:30:00 17.45165       NA
#2      ana 2015-01-01 18:00:00 19.00659 17.45165
#3      bob 2015-01-01 09:07:00 14.40996       NA
#4      bob 2015-01-01 18:05:00 13.64010 14.40996
#5 caroline 2015-01-01 11:11:00 14.50865       NA
#6 caroline 2015-01-01 19:20:00 12.08506 14.50865
```

However, you can avoid using `arrange()` with `order_by()`.

```
group_by(mydf, id) %>%
mutate(check = lag(value, order_by = order))

#        id               order    value    check
#1      ana 2015-01-01 18:00:00 19.00659 17.45165
#2      bob 2015-01-01 18:05:00 13.64010 14.40996
#3 caroline 2015-01-01 19:20:00 12.08506 14.50865
#4      bob 2015-01-01 09:07:00 14.40996       NA
#5      ana 2015-01-01 08:30:00 17.45165       NA
#6 caroline 2015-01-01 11:11:00 14.50865       NA
```

EXPERIMENT

I wanted to apply the same procedure to the case in which I wanted
to assign row number to a new column. Using the sample data, you can do the folowing.

```
group_by(mydf, id) %>%
arrange(order) %>%
mutate(num = row_number())

#        id               order    value num
#1      ana 2015-01-01 08:30:00 17.45165   1
#2      ana 2015-01-01 18:00:00 19.00659   2
#3      bob 2015-01-01 09:07:00 14.40996   1
#4      bob 2015-01-01 18:05:00 13.64010   2
#5 caroline 2015-01-01 11:11:00 14.50865   1
#6 caroline 2015-01-01 19:20:00 12.08506   2
```

Can we omit the arrange line? Seeing the CRAN manual, I did the following.
Both attempts were not successful.

```
### Not working
group_by(mydf, id) %>%
mutate(num = row_number(order_by = order))

### Not working
group_by(mydf, id) %>%
mutate(num = order_by(order, row_number()))
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not mean to answer this question by myself. But, I decided to share
what I found given I have not seen many posts using `order_by` and particularly
`with_order`. My answer was to use `with_order()` instead of `order_by()`.

```
group_by(mydf, id) %>%
mutate(num = with_order(order_by = order, fun = row_number, x = order))

#        id               order    value num
#1      ana 2015-01-01 18:00:00 19.00659   2
#2      bob 2015-01-01 18:05:00 13.64010   2
#3 caroline 2015-01-01 19:20:00 12.08506   2
#4      bob 2015-01-01 09:07:00 14.40996   1
#5      ana 2015-01-01 08:30:00 17.45165   1
#6 caroline 2015-01-01 11:11:00 14.50865   1
```

I wanted to see if there would be any difference between the two
approaches in terms of speed. It seems that they are pretty similar in this case.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mydf2 <- data.frame(id = rep(c("ana", "bob", "caroline",
                               "bob", "ana", "caroline"), times = 200000),
                    order = seq(as.POSIXct("2015-03-01 18:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 18:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                length.out = 1200000),
                    value = runif(1200000, 10, 20),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

jazz1 <- function() {group_by(mydf2, id) %>%
                     arrange(order) %>%
                     mutate(num = row_number())}

jazz2 <- function() {group_by(mydf2, id) %>%
                     mutate(num = with_order(order_by = order, fun = row_number, x = order))}


res <- microbenchmark(jazz1, jazz2, times = 1000000L)
res

#Unit: nanoseconds
#  expr min lq     mean median uq   max neval cld
# jazz1  32 36 47.17647     38 47 12308 1e+06   a
# jazz2  32 36 47.02902     38 47 12402 1e+06   a
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing the function `with_order`

Comment: @akrun You are welcome. :) I somehow started this journey this morning when I was thinking about a question. There seems to be no example for `with_order` in R Help yet. I thought this would be a good chance to contribute something to the community.